How to retrieve latest versions for multiple models in ML Flow without requiring multiple calls to getLatestVersions endpoint?
I'm trying to integrate the ML Flow models loading into my project. On ML Flow I have multiple models uploaded and with multiple versions within. So, what I'm trying to do is to retrieve the latest version for every model I have on ML Flow. One way I can do this is to search for the prefix that I named every model, like:
 client.searchModelVersions("name LIKE '" + MODEL_PREFIX + "%'");

This will delivers a Page object that will allow me to iterate across the models I have. And with the models in hand I can get the name of each one and retrieve the latest version. Like:
modelVersions
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                ModelVersion::getName,
                modelVersion -> {
                  List<ModelVersion> versionsForModel =
                      client.getLatestVersions(modelVersion.getName());
                  return versionsForModel.get(versionsForModel.size() - 1);
                },
                (alreadyComputedModel, newModel) -> alreadyComputedModel))
        .values()
        .stream();

But as you can see this is an inefficient since I have to ask for the ML Flow API multiple times for every model name.
Is there a method/parameters I can use for the ML Flow always delivers me the latest versions of the models in batch?

I was able to resolve this in memory since ML Flow, apparently, doesn't have an endpoint for this.
private Stream<ModelVersion> getLatestVersionsForModels(Stream<ModelVersion> modelVersions) {
    return modelVersions
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                ModelVersion::getName,
                modelVersion -> modelVersion,
                (alreadyComputedModel, newModel) ->
                    Integer.parseInt(alreadyComputedModel.getVersion())
                            > Integer.parseInt(newModel.getVersion())
                        ? alreadyComputedModel
                        : newModel))
        .values()
        .stream();

